# ArcGIS Online - Legend for raster/image (in web map, web map app, via Image service or other)

Tags: raster, arcgis-online, legend, image-service

Is there a way to have an AGO map, or mapping application, with rasters than be symbolised in the legend?

We currently use Image Services which load fine but cannot be listed in the legend - so the symbology becomes a little useless.

Is there a way to attach legend properties to the image service?

If we were to switch to a WMS would that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent update allows for mosaic datasets to have the symbology embedded in the file properties.

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/12/10/customizing-the-display-of-image-services-in-arcgis-com-map-viewer/

Alternatively convert it to a vector layer but depending on the nature of the data this could lead to long load times.